# Inserting a new column into SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have these queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.GRAUD_ProjectsByCostCategory

select right(CostCategoryId,14) as CostBreak 
from dbo.GRAUD_ProjectsByCostCategory
```

They work well in that they give me the correct data, but I would like to know how to combine the new column `CostBreak` into the table of results rather than as a separate query result.

An example of the results I get are as below:

[image]

Where I want them in the same table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data is coming from the same table so you should be able to just add that value to your initial query. You do not even have to perform a join to get it:

```
SELECT name, 
  description, 
  project,
  CostCategoryId, 
  right(CostCategoryId,14) as CostBreak 
FROM dbo.GRAUD_ProjectsByCostCategory
```